# Conditionally Include Modules in application.config.php?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

With Zend Framework 2, is there a built in means to load certain modules if certain route conditions are met?

Here's a really bad example.  Imagine a Login and Registration page were built as separate modules, one would know that the Login module needn't be instantiated with /register is the present route.

If you can look past my horrible example, I think the logic is sound…  Some modules provide a breath of listeners and triggers that simply aren't used unless their route is at play.  Trying to avoid the bootstrap overhead where  possible on a site that serves thousands per minute.

Thought I'd ask around before I roll some means to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this isn't too late. I needed to solve a similar problem where I wanted to load the Cli module only when working from cli. This is what I do in my application.config.php file

```
    return call_user_func(function() {

        $modules = array(
            'Application',
        );

        if (\Zend\Console\Console::isConsole()) {
            $modules[] = 'Cli';
        } else {
            $modules[] = 'Api';
            $modules[] = 'Mobile';
        }

        return array(
            'modules' => $modules,
            // Other application config options
        );    
    });
```

Typically this file would have had "return array(/* ... */);" but by making it into a function, you can apply any logic you like.

Comment: Ah sonofa, I never thought of this, that's a great idea.  I solved it differently, but will definitely award marks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it may be possible to conditionally load modules, it won't be based on a route, as all the application routes live in modules. How would ZF2 know which modules might have routes with 'module loading' conditions attached without loading them first?

The module bootstrap overhead in ZF2 is pretty low. This is an area that was improved considerably over ZF1. It's unlikely that this will be a bottleneck for your application, so don't try and solve a problem unless you know it exists.